# docker-compose run multiple tasks without sharing dependencies

Tags: selenium, docker, docker-compose

**The situation:** 
I have a `selenium app` (in python) which connects itself to an account on a website in order to download several CSV files.
To run it, I use `docker` (and `docker-compose`) here's my `docker-compose.yml` file

```
version: '3'

services:
  selenium:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: compose/selenium/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "4444:4444"
    volumes:
      - /dev/shm:/dev/shm
      - download-folder:/home/seluser/downloads

  enma:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: compose/enma_daio/Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - selenium
    volumes:
      - download-folder:/data/selenium-downloads
    env_file:
      - .env
    restart: always

volumes:
  download-folder:
```

My `selenium's Dockerfile` is just a way to create the `downloads` folder with the official [selenium docker image](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium)

```
FROM selenium/standalone-chrome

RUN mkdir -p /home/seluser/downloads
```

To run my task I use:

```
docker-compose run -d enma daio arg0 arg1 arg2
```

By the way, I also use an entrypoint.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

cd /app

# Selenium takes a bit of time before being up so we wait until we can reach it
function selenium_ready(){
  curl selenium:4444 &>/dev/null
}

until selenium_ready; do
  >&2 echo "Waiting for selenium..."
  sleep 1
done


if [ "$1" = 'daio' ]; then
    shift
    exec python enma.py $@
fi

exec "$@"
```

**The problem:**
When I run multiple instances at the same time (on different accounts on the same website), they share the `same selenium container` and so the `same volume`. All Downloaded files are mixed together and I can't know which file comes which `run`.

**What I would like to do:**
I would like to create another `selenium container` every time I run a new task. Or find the other way to use different volumes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds like you should pass the `--project-name` or `p` flag to docker-compose when doing `docker-compose run`.

By default docker-compose creates volume and container names based on your project name with the name of the current directory as a default. So in your case you will have a volume name `<cwd>_download-folder`. With container names `<cwd>_selenium` and `<cwd>_enma`.

If you want to have new volumes and a new `selenium` container created on each `docker-compose run` you just need to override its project name.

So if you do

`$ docker-compose -p name1 run -d enma daio arg0 arg1 arg2`

`$ docker-compose -p name2 run -d enma daio arg0 arg1 arg2`

You will end up with two created volumes, and four containers. Which seems to suit your needs, this will eliminate the `enma` containers from sharing the same volume.

FYI you can view which volumes have been created by running `docker volume ls`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you ! This is exactly what I was looking for ! Now I have to manage dynamic ports as I can't give all selenium 4444. But this is easy to manage through environment variables using `-e KEY=VAL` option. Which would result in 
`$ docker-compose -p name1 run -e SELENIUM_PORT=4444 -d enma daio arg0 arg1 arg2`
`$ docker-compose -p name2 run -e SELENIUM_PORT=4445 -d enma daio arg0 arg1 arg2`

Comment: Well I making it hard for no reason, just had to remove the `ports: 4444:4444` because I don't need to expose it.